# SPARC Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, sparc

I am trying to run a sample Sparc assembly language , but I am not even sure where to start. I tried `vim macro` or `m4 example.m` but I dont know where and how to compile it. I searched the internet, read articles, but none of them mentioned how to start coding.

for example, I would like to type this assembly language :

```
.global main
 main:  save    %sp, -96, %sp   

 mov    PROMPT, %o0 
 call   writeChar
 nop
 call   readInt
```

what commend should I use to compile and run ? (using Linux)

Comment: Are you asking how to use an editor to type in assembler code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "compile" assembly code, you "assemble" it!  That said, your compiler driver can probably do it.  A common filename extension for assembly source code is `.s`, so maybe something like:

```
cc -o example example.s
```

Then, if it worked, you'll have an executable named `example` to run, test, and debug.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, how do you run that example file?

Comment: ./example ... ?